# JScrollPane doesn't dispatch event

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane, mouselistener

I have a `JTable` inside `JScrollPane` inside `JPanel`. And I have a `MouseListener` added to the last `JPanel`. The problem is, I can't listen to mouse events when mouse pressed on free space outside `JTable`. I have another `JPanel` with `JTextField` in it, and it dispatches events to its parent `JPanel`. May be there is some property to set at `JScrollPane`?

**SSCCE:**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class SimpleTableDemo extends JPanel {

    public SimpleTableDemo() {
        super(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        String[] columnNames = { "First Name", "Last Name", "Sport", "# of Years", "Vegetarian" };

        Object[][] data = { { "Kathy", "Smith", "Snowboarding", new Integer(5), new Boolean(false) }, { "John", "Doe", "Rowing", new Integer(3), new Boolean(true) }, { "Sue", "Black", "Knitting", new Integer(2), new Boolean(false) }, { "Jane", "White", "Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true) }, { "Joe", "Brown", "Pool", new Integer(10), new Boolean(false) } };

        final JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));
        table.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(false);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

        add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel textPanel = new JPanel();
        JTextField textField = new JTextField(50);
        textPanel.add(textField);
        add(textPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println("PRESSED!!!");
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SimpleTableDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(700, 400);

        SimpleTableDemo newContentPane = new SimpleTableDemo();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true);
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: MouseListener is added to JPanel then all mousePressed outside of JTextField must firing an Event, another MouseEvent there isn't added, intialized

Comment: @mKorbel Maybe `GlassPane` should do the job ?

Comment: @Little Child there is possible to redispatch an event (clear is oonly OPs comment to jzd answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for example (based on comments here)

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class LostMouseEvent {

    private JPanel panel1 = new JPanel() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(600, 400);
        }
    };
    private JPanel panel2 = new JPanel() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(500, 300);
        }
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new LostMouseEvent();
            }
        });
    }

    public LostMouseEvent() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(panel2);
                panel1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.blue));
                panel2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.green));
                panel1.add(pane);
                MouseListener rml = new RealMouseListener();
                panel1.addMouseListener(rml);
                MouseListener fml = new FakeMouseListener();
                pane.addMouseListener(fml);
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(panel1);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);

            }
        });
    }

    private class RealMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
            System.out.println(me);
            Point point = me.getPoint();
            //System.out.println(point);
            System.out.println(me.getX());
            System.out.println(me.getXOnScreen());
            System.out.println(me.getY());
            System.out.println(me.getYOnScreen());
        }
    }

    private class FakeMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
            JScrollPane pane = (JScrollPane) me.getSource();
            MouseEvent newMe = SwingUtilities.convertMouseEvent(panel2/*pane.getViewport()*/, me, panel1);
            System.out.println(newMe.getX());
            System.out.println(newMe.getXOnScreen());
            System.out.println(newMe.getY());
            System.out.println(newMe.getYOnScreen());
            panel1.dispatchEvent(me);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But why `JPanel` redispatches `MouseEvent` by default, and `JScrollPane` - no?

Comment: you need to catch this events from `JViewport`, to `disable panel2` and uncomment `/*pane.getViewport()*/` (already prepared for this question), only `JViewport` (visible `Rectange` from `JScrollPane`) can interact with `Mouse Events`

Comment: thanks, it works as expected but it is better to use `pane` instead of `pane.getViewport()` because of mouse coordinates.

Comment: glad if help you, but proper of ways is usage of corrdinate from JScrollPanes child(s)

Comment: in case when `JTable` is inside `JScrollPane`, the `JTableHeader` is added at the top of `JScrollPane` as another `JViewport` and `y` coordinate of `MouseEvent` becomes wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `MouseListener` to the `JScrollPane` directly and then you will be able to get click events from that section of the GUI.

In your SSCCE change this line:

```
 addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
```

to:

```
 scrollPane.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
```

And you should be able to test this.

Comment: No, I can't do that. I need to dispatch it to `JPanel` from `JScrollPane`

Comment: Not sure what you mean by dispatch.  You can add the listener to both objects.

Comment: The `JScrollPane` has no access to `JPanel'` `MouseListener`, so I can't do that.

Comment: +1 for answer and comment too, there no idea for why reason to redispatch an event to parent, out of practical idea nor reason

Comment: @SeniorJD please whats reason you can to use SwingUtilities to convert from to, there are three or four methods

Comment: @SeniorJD It doesn't matter.  The MouseListener doesn't have to be inside of the scroll pane. It can be part of the SimpleTableDemo class, listening to both the SimpleTableDemo and the scrollpane.

Comment: @mKorbel The reason is: At the moment, when I add the `JScrollPane` to `JPanel`, my `MouseListener` isn't added yet, and when I add it, there is no info about `JScrollPane` inside `JPanel`. @jzd it matter a lot actually.